# Why UniswapV3 calls `_approve` in permit function?

Tags: solidity, erc-20, uniswap, signature, transferfrom

As far as I know, `permit` function is implemented to avoid calling `approve` function before calling the `transferFrom`. That way instead of calling two functions for transfer, we would call only one function. Technically, `permit` function by-pass calling `approve` function by signing the transaction and then this signature gets verified on chain. But at the end of `permit` function, it calls the `_approve` function. From [ERC721Permit.sol](https://github.com/Uniswap/v3-periphery/blob/main/contracts/base/ERC721Permit.sol)

```
function permit(
    address spender,
    uint256 tokenId,
    uint256 deadline,
    uint8 v,
    bytes32 r,
    bytes32 s
) external payable override {
    require(_blockTimestamp() <= deadline, 'Permit expired');
    bytes32 digest = keccak256(
        abi.encodePacked(
            '\x19\x01',
            DOMAIN_SEPARATOR(),
            keccak256(abi.encode(PERMIT_TYPEHASH, spender, tokenId, _getAndIncrementNonce(tokenId), deadline))
        )
    );
    address owner = ownerOf(tokenId);
    require(spender != owner, 'ERC721Permit: approval to current owner');

    if (Address.isContract(owner)) {
        require(IERC1271(owner).isValidSignature(digest, abi.encodePacked(r, s, v)) == 0x1626ba7e, 'Unauthorized');
    } else {
        address recoveredAddress = ecrecover(digest, v, r, s);
        require(recoveredAddress != address(0), 'Invalid signature');
        require(recoveredAddress == owner, 'Unauthorized');
    }
    _approve(spender, tokenId);
}
```

}

Why did `_approve` get called in `permit`?

Answer (score 0):

The permit function is essentially a way for someone else to call approve for the user instead of the user having to launch two transactions. In the erc20 implementation though, we still need to update the approval storage data for that user. Notice we call the internal helper function `_approve` and not `approve`. The _approve function increases the allowance data for a user, which is something we need to do whether the user calls approve themselves, or uses a permit for someone or some contract to set the approval for them.

Think of permit as calling approve with a signature as permissioning, rather than msg.sender as permissioning.

In terms of how it works using the permit, we still do essentially "call approve for the user", we just use a signature to verify that the user wanted it called, instead of requiring the user to have sent the transaction from their wallet.

For something like using a permit so the user only has to launch one transaction to say do a swap, the user can send the permit data to the contract along with its call to swap, and then the contract can update the user's approval on the users behalf.

This saves the user from launching two transactions, but also saves overall gas since there is a base cost per transaction of about ~21k gas per transaction if I recall correctly, and ecrecover costs about 3k gas.